# How do i webscrape the data in "preview" under "network" using requests?

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests

For example in for this highchart:
https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line

I am trying to web-scrape this information
[image: under network --> preview]

[image]

Each dropdown has information that i need to collect for analysis. Currently i am trying to use the Requests package in python without much success

Would love to hear any advice!

Comment: What do you have so far? What did you try?

Comment: So far, i only have the code to requests.get(url). unfortunately i am new to requests package, so i have not tried anything really useful. i know that you go to https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/aapl-c.json via the Request URL(under "headers"), however on the actual site that i am working on, going to the link via Request URL will result in "405: Method Not Allowed"

Comment: On the actual site, the Request method is "Post"

Comment: That json endpoint supports GET requests, maybe you're getting 405 errors because you're trying to send POST requests?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, use `requests.get` to make a get request, then use `.json` method to parse response as a json, then optionally convert timestamps (given in ms, divide by 1000 to get seconds) into `datetime` objects like this:

```py
import requests
from datetime import datetime
from pprint import pprint


def get_stock_prices(symbol: str) -> list:
    symbol = symbol.lower()
    url = f'https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/{symbol}-c.json'
    res = requests.get(url)
    res.raise_for_status()
    prices_raw = res.json()
    return [[datetime.fromtimestamp(t / 1000), price] 
            for t, price in prices_raw]


symbol = 'AAPL'
stocks = get_stock_prices(symbol)
pprint(stocks)
```

output:

```
[[datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 17, 16, 30), 149.56],
 [datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 18, 16, 30), 150.08],
 [datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 19, 16, 30), 151.02],
 [datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 20, 16, 30), 150.34],
 [datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 21, 16, 30), 150.27],
 [datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 24, 16, 30), 152.09],
 [datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 25, 16, 30), 152.74],
 [datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 26, 16, 30), 153.46],
```